# How to add new item in Cosmosdb from Azure API management inbound policy

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-api-management

I am trying to save my large payload to cosmosdb from my inbound policy in Azure API management.
From my inbound policy I am able to put the content in Azure blob, also able to put the request in service bus queue, only not able to put it in the CosmosDb.
Plan is to save very large payload in the blob, get the blob address put it in the Cosmosdb, and pass that cosmosdb entry detail to the service bus. If payload is not that large, put the whole payload in CosmosDb and pass the CosmosDb entry detail to the service bus.
So, payload size will not impact the way my service will read the payload, it will always come from CosmosDb, sometimes direct, and if large via Blob storage.
My step looks like:

```
<send-request mode="new" response-variable-name="cosmosstate" timeout="30" ignore-error="false">
    <set-url>https://somethin.documents.azure.com:443/dbs/tempdb/colls/tempcoll/docs</set-url>
    <set-method>POST</set-method>
    <set-header name="Authorization" exists-action="override">
        <value>@("type=aad&ver=1.0&sig="+context.Variables["msi-access-token-cosmos"])</value>
    </set-header>
    <set-header name="x-ms-date" exists-action="override">
        <value>@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("requestDateString"))</value>
    </set-header>
    <set-header name="x-ms-version" exists-action="override">
        <value>2018-12-31</value>
    </set-header>
    <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
        <value>application/x-www-form-urlencoded</value>
    </set-header>
    <set-body>@((string)context.Variables["cosmoscontent"])</set-body>
</send-request>
```

Through testing, I know that values in the variables are correct.

Comment: Please have look here. Maybe it helps you to start: https://anthonychu.ca/post/azure-api-management-look-up-user-cosmos-db/

Comment: Thanks @MarkusMeyer, tried the approaches there over last 2 days, but still no luck in posting data. I got the read samples there but not write part.